# How to add a property/ styles to child nodes inside a parent element in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I had a table

```
<table>
 <thead> 
  <tr> </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody> 
  <tr> </tr> 
 </tboday>
</table>
```

I want to add a property to `<tr>` inside `<tbody>` not `<thead>`

After I add this line
`(<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('tr')).setAttribute("draggable", "true");`

the table looks like

```
<table>
 <thead> 
  <tr draggable=true> </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody> 
  <tr> </tr>  // note here there is no above mentioned property. I need to put here
 </tboday>
</table>
```

How can I add  `draggable=true` to `<tr>` inside `<tobdy>`

Answer (score 0):

this will help you

```js
document.querySelector('tbody tr').setAttribute("draggable", "true");
```

```html
<table>
 <thead> 
  <tr></tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody> 
  <tr>here </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```